# Gmail snooze until 7 days (one week)?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to define a Gmail snooze until 7 days, in addition to the default ones being Later Today, Tomorrow, This Weekend, Next week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Yes**.

**One can define a custom "snooze" of days as well as the time of the day by clicking on `Select date and time`.**

[image]

**On the following screen one can change both the days as well as the time of the day.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add this to the preselection menu?

Comment: No. Unfortunately that is not possible.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.